# Why running `npm create vite@latest` or `npm install` throws error conection?

Tags: npm, operating-system, npm-install, vite, react-typescript

I am trying to create a new project with Vite but there is a problem with the request

I run this command `npm create vite@latest` and shows the following

```js
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! errno EACCES
npm ERR! FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/create-vite failed, reason: connect EACCES 2606:4700::6810:1623:443
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/minipass-fetch/lib/index.js:130:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:512:28)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:496:9)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:524:35)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
npm ERR!     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
npm ERR!  FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/create-vite failed, reason: connect EACCES 2606:4700::6810:1623:443
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/minipass-fetch/lib/index.js:130:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:512:28)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:496:9)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:524:35)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
npm ERR!     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   errno: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'connect',
npm ERR!   address: '2606:4700::6810:1623',
npm ERR!   port: 443,
npm ERR!   type: 'system'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/wenanoshe/.npm/_logs/2023-02-22T20_27_32_249Z-debug-0.log
```

I tried removing npm from my machine and installing it again, but the problem persists and tried running as administrator but did not work

Comment: The problem was in my internet connection, I just called my internet provider and they restarted the router